# Trying to understand how to use Angular-mock

Tags: angularjs, testing

All:

I am pretty new to Angular Testing, from its docs:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/unit-testing

There is one example:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {
  $scope.password = '';
  $scope.grade = function() {
    var size = $scope.password.length;
    if (size > 8) {
      $scope.strength = 'strong';
    } else if (size > 3) {
      $scope.strength = 'medium';
    } else {
      $scope.strength = 'weak';
    }
  };
});
```

And the test specs:

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

I wonder what did Angular-Mock do, why we can directly use those function like "inject", **where did we include that module**(or did it bind that function to WINDOW global object when loading?)? And **how does that inject function tell** if that injection is for a controller or directive and etcs, I find they all use same inject function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [Angular ngMock documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) says:

> angular.mock.module    NOTE: This function is also published on window
> for easy access.
>
> angular.mock.inject    NOTE: This function is also published on window
> for easy access.

that is why you can access those function directly.

The inject function it's only a easy way to reach the services like you were injecting them in your service/directive/controller/...: they are simple singletons, don't need to be *for* something.

Comment: Thanks and Ooops, I am for sure not a good student. But I do not catch the inject part, I mean from its signature, when inject controller and directive, both just put a callback-like function as parameter of inject function, but the parameter of that callback-like means different, I just wonder how does inject function know what we want to inject( does it decide by the number of parameters)?

Comment: There is an [interesting post](http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2013/02/11/the-magic-behind-angularjs-dependency-injection.html) about this: it calls `toString` on the callback, it takes all the arguments names and injects the right things at the right place.